# WebRTC simple app is stuck at iceConnectionState = 'new'. Connection doesn't seem to be made

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peer

I have made a simple webRTC app that tries to send a video stream from p1 to p2. Both the peers are on the same browser and hence share the same local network. Offer and answer (and remote and local setup in the correct order) succesfully setup. I am receiving the 'icecandidate' event but 'candidate' property is null for both peers, so I am not calling addIceCandidate function of the other rtcPeerConnection. After all this the iceConnectionState is still 'new'. Also I am not receiving the track event on the peerConnection Object of the receiving peer even after adding the tracks on the sender peer Object. I want to know where I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: That is weird. I assume that the RTCPeerConnection iceGatheringState is "complete"?
Receiving null as candidate means that every adress has been gathered, but it seems like none of the local addresses have been found (neither 127.0.0.1 nor your local IP).
Can you perhaps post your current code?

Comment: You can use [simple-peer] (https://github.com/feross/simple-peer) . A wrapper of the RTCpeerconnection basically. I had the same problem as what you mentioned; never got it to work. But with simple-peer it found the ice candidates like it should.